# Web-based conversion shp to json

Tags: json, xml, google-maps, shapefile

I'm currently working on a school project that implements Google Maps overlayed with data stored in shapefiles and a xml file with a bitmap in it and the WGS coordinates where the image should be overlayed.

The web application that needs to be build requires that a user uploads these raw files, and the result should be visible in the Google Maps.

Is there any way to convert these shapefiles to .json, using PHP or javascript, and get the coordinates stored in the .xml file to get the WGS coordinates. This needs to be done web-based, so stand-alone tools and software won't be sufficient.

These coordinates and .json files than need to be stored in a database, and these records will be used to put on the Google Maps with the appropriate overlays on the resulted coordinates.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All of the processing will need to be done on the server side.  I was able to find a shapefile reader class written in php here,

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1741-PHP-Read-vectorial-data-from-geographic-shape-files.html

It sounds like you have a pretty decent handle on how you need to go about solving the rest of the problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

js-shapefiles-to-geojson script renders shapefiles and dbf files entirely on the client-side, in the browser.

repo: https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson
demo: http://wavded.github.io/js-shapefile-to-geojson/